# javascript+jquery check if element exists, then set its value, else something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, exists

I'm trying to check if a textfield exists withing another element, and I want to set its value if it does; otherwise, I want to add a radio. I've got the following code, but it's not working.

```
$("ul").each(function(){
if ( !($(this).find('input[value="9999"]').val()) ) {
    var textfield = $(this).find('input[type="text"]');
    if ( textfield.length ) textfield.value="9999";
    // ^ this doesn't work. have also tried if ($(textfield).val())
    else $(this).append('<input name="'+name+'" type="radio" value="9999" checked="checked" />');
    // ^ this works
} // if
});
```

btw, `name` is set dynamically earlier in the script.

**Answer**:

```
$("ul").each(function(){
if ( !($(this).find('input[value="9999"]').val()) ) {
    var txtfield = $(this).find('input[type="text"]');
    if ( txtfield.length ) $(txtfield).val("9999");
    // just changed this ^ line (above)
    else $(this).append('<input name="'+name+'" type="radio" value="9999" checked="checked" />');
} // if
});
```

Comment: did you try setting the value of the text field as `$(textfield).val("9999")`?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="foo" />` or `<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" />`

Comment: thanks @Anurag. since you were first, wanna put it as an answer and i'll mark it?

Answer (score 1):

textfield is a jquery object already so you will need to set the value by using textfield.val("9999")

Answer (score 0):

.find() will also return a list of elements, so if there are more than one, this may not work. You may need to do another .each() on the textfield variable.

Comment: hmm…I would have expected the `textfield.value="9999"` to execute on the first element from the find if that were the case, but I'll try the `.each()`.